# Martingale problem for regime switching SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mu$ be a continuous time Markov process switching between two possible values $a, b \in \mathbb R$ with time homogeneous transition rates. Consider the one dimensional SDE

$$dX_t = \mu \, dt + dW_t$$

with $W$ a standard Brownian motion independent of $\mu$.

Is it true that $X$ solves a martingale problem? And if so, what is the generator?

Comment: The generator $L$ acting on a function $f$ of the position of the process and the possible values of $\mu$ is defined by $$ L f(x, c) = f’(x) c + f’’(x)/2 + \lambda_{a \to b} ( f(x, b) - f(x,c) ) + \lambda_{b \to a} (f(x,a)-f(x,c)) \;.$$ It does indeed solve the martingale problem for the operator $L$ acting on continuously differentiable and globally Lipschitz functions.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll verify this as an exercise..